# Spring boot 2 - memcached

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, memcached

I'm trying to create a cache using memcached with lib https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot

I think I have done everything but it does not work.
My code is:

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.sixhours</groupId>
        <artifactId>memcached-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

apllication.yml

```
memcached.cache:
  servers: localhost:11211
  mode: static
  expirations: 3600
```

app. code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class CRMProxyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

---

```
 @Cacheable("couponCache")
 @GetMapping(path = Mappings.GET_BEST_OF_AMAZON, produces = 
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<Object> getCouponList(@RequestParam(value = "p_client_uid") Integer pClientUID) {
        return new ResponseEntity<> (couponManagementService.getCouponList(pClientUID), HttpStatus.OK);}
```

---

When application starting, log show

```
 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
```

Using Spring Boot version 2.0.6
MacOS

What am I doing wrong ? :)

PS: If if anyone has a working example pls share.

Comment: What is wrong? What is the issue you are facing? Also, try moving the @Cacheable to the service layer

Comment: Your setup looks perfectly fine and the `MemcachedConnection` log shows app is connected to the memcached server. I do see that you are using `1.3.0` version of the library, please use the latest one `1.3.2` which does allow some additional options for configuring the caching. I've updated the demo application to match your version of Spring Boot, do take a [look](https://github.com/igorbolic/spring-boot-memcached-demo-java/tree/stackoverflow) and check the README file for more info. Also, do move the caching to the service layer, instead of caching the Spring controller responses.